# How to read binary type column in parquet file by AWS Redshift Spectrum?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, parquet, clickhouse, amazon-redshift-spectrum

I have a parquet file generated by clickhouse, if use pyarrow to show its schema:

```
import pyarrow.parquet as pq

data = pq.read_table('test.pqt')
print(data.schema)
```

It shows the schema was like this:

```
team_id: binary not null
project_id: uint32 not null
user_id: binary not null
```

And I try to create a external table in Redshift to read this data file:

```
CREATE external TABLE spectrum.my_test_table
(
    team_id varbyte(64),
    project_id bigint,
    user_id varbyte(64)
)
```

But Spectrum return an exception saying:

```
error: Spectrum Scan Error code: 15007 context: File 'https://s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/my_bucket/my_parquet.pqt' uses an unsupported compression: 7 for column 'team_id'
```

I also try to use `VARCHAR` instead of `VARBYTE` but the error was the same. How can I read these binary columns using Redshift Spectrum?

====Update====

I do some more test on this problem, and I found all columns in parquet generated by Clickhouse would have this error in Redshift:

```
xxx.parquet uses an unsupported compression: 7 for column xxx
```

Even for those int or string columns, what's wrong with Clickhouse's parquet?

Comment: It looks like the compression format used by your parquet file is not supported by spectrum. What does `pq.ParquetFile("test.pqt").metadata.to_dict()` tell you about the compression format? Is it `LZ4`?

Comment: @0x26res Yes it was! I checked the document of Clickhouse and found `lz4` was its default compression, but Redshift doesn't support this. So I change the compression to `gzip` and it's alright now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @0x26res said, I found the `lz4` was the default compression of Clickhouse which is not supported by Redshift. So I change the compression to `gzip` in Clickhouse and it's alright now.